# MKAnnotation view's frame is not being converted properly

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, dictionary, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I want to have a MKAnnotation view with the same frame as my map view and have it go directly on top of the map view.

So in the method :

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id )annotation

I initialise the MKAnnotation view's frame to be

CGRectMake(0,0,map.frame.size.width,map.frame.size.height).

Then I use annotationView.frame = [map convertRect:annotationView.frame toView:annotationView];

This seems to work well but only sometimes. Sometimes the annotationView's frame would be 1 pixel out from the left side of the screen, and other times it would be 1 pixel out from the right side of the screen.

Can anyone give any tips?

Thanks

Note: MKOverlay is not an option as I am using another class that inherits from MKAnnotationView. I just want to know why the conversion is not happening properly.

Comment: Are you testing on a real device? looks like some math conversion is not being accurate enough or it happens to soon or too late, remember that all UI updates are performed on the main thread.